# Count the Opposite Technique

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Assume repetition is allowed and uppercase, lowercase and 0-9 are allowed, how many 8 char. passwords are possible where at least one 1 char that is uppercase at the beginning OR 1 char is a digit at end of password.

I compensated for overcounting by taking $62^8$ and subtracting it by $26 * 10$

so my answer is ($62^8 - (26 * 10)$) is this correct?

Comment: Recall $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$. So if $A$ is the set of passwords that starts with a lowercase or a digit and $B$ is the set of passwords that does not end in a digit you want $|T\setminus (A\cup B)|$ where T are all passwords in that charset with 8 characters.

Comment: is |A intersects B| just 62^6? @Phicar

Comment: Is that but multiplied by the choices you have in the first ($36$) and the last character ($52$).

Comment: @Phicar ahhhh that makes sense, so the final answer is 62^8-((62^7(26) + 62^7(10)) - (62^6(36)(52)) ???

Comment: Nop, see that in $A$ you can start with a lowercase or with a digit and in $B$ you can start with a lowercase or an uppercase.

Comment: 62^8-((62^7(36) + 62^7(52)) - (62^6(36)(52)) how about this?

Comment: Yes, i was thinking that but i made a mistake, i did not see the "OR" you have pretty big. You want $|A\cup B|$ where $A$ is the set of passwords that start with an uppercase and $B$ is the set of passwords that end with a digit, so you do not need to take complements. Sorry, but the arithmetics is the same. ;)

Comment: oh okay, so it's just this again:  62^8-((62^7(26) + 62^7(10)) - (62^6(36)(52)) @Phicar

Comment: No, i made the error in the first comment...forget the complement, the answer would be just $62^7*26+62^7*10-62^6*26*10$ see the last sets i wrote about. Sorry.

Comment: ahhhhh I see now, thank you, no worries on that error! @Phicar